# Multiple objects in touchesbegan?

Tags: iphone, touches

I am trying to have multiple objects in a touchesbegan method (2 UIImageViews)

I am using the below code but isn't working. No errors but the location is just messed up. What should I do instead?

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

    if (image1.image == [UIImage imageNamed:@"ball.png"]){
         CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
         image1.center = location;
    }
    if (image1.image == [UIImage imageNamed:@"ball2.png"]){
         CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
         image2.center = location;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to identify both image view in touchesbegen try this

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event //here enable the touch       
 {
// get touch event


UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];
if (CGRectContainsPoint(image1.frame, touchLocation))
{
    NSLog(@"image1 touched");
    //Your logic
}
if (CGRectContainsPoint(image2.frame, touchLocation))
{
    NSLog(@"image2 touched");
            //your logic
}
     }
```

Hope this help

Comment: Hey, your code works great! But it doesn't work with multiple touch. I need to be able to drag both images at the same time. Here is my code:
 - (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
   UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
      CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];
   
 Part 2 below...

Comment: if (CGRectContainsPoint(image1.frame, touchLocation))
   {
    NSLog(@"image1 touched");
    //Your logic
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
    image1.center = location;
   }
   if (CGRectContainsPoint(image2.frame, touchLocation))
   {
    NSLog(@"image2 touched");
    //your logic
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
    image2.center = location;
   }
     }

Answer (score 0):

I guess, `image1.image` in your second `if` condition needs to `image2.image` if you need to over lap `image1` and `image2` center. But if you need to move the images you have to do the follow -

1. Check whether the touch point belongs to both the objects.
2. If yes, move both the images relatively.( i.e., add the moved amount to the earlier image center ). Not making the touch point as the image center location.

Ex: If `image1` center is at (x1, y1) and `image2` center is at (x2, y2). Now the touch point (x3, y3) belongs both to image `image1` and `image2`. If the new dragged is at (x4,y4), the drag amount is `x4-x3` and `y4-y3` along `x,y` directions respectively. Add this drag amount to both the image's center for the image to appear at the new location.

---

**Pseudo Code**

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];

    float touchXBeginPoint = [touch locationInView:touch.view].x;
    float touchYBeginPoint = [touch locationInView:touch.view].y;

    // Now Check touchXBeginPoint, touchYBeginPoint lies in image1, image2
    // Calculate the offset distance.

    if( /* both are true */ )
    {

       // Add the offset amount to the image1, image2 center.

    }

    else if( /* image1 touch is true */ )
    {
         // Add the offset amount to the image1 center
    }

    else if( /* image2 touch is true */ )
    {
         // Add the offset amount to the image2 center
    }
}
```

Download the source code of [iPhone Game Dev](http://apress.com/book/view/9781430225997) chapter 3 and see how images are being moved.

Comment: I just changed it, but I do not want to overlap it. I want each UIImageView to have it own position and to be able to dragged around at the same time.

Comment: I am really confused. The touch point will always not equal both images so I want to eliminate that. This is how far I am: 
 - (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
 UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
 
 if (image1.image == [UIImage imageNamed:@"ball.png"]){
  CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
  image1.center = location;
 }
  if (image2.image == [UIImage imageNamed:@"ball2.png"]){
   CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
   image2.center = location;
  }
 }